# Buyer's remorse, MSE style

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I posted an answer to this question [$m^2+2017=n^3$ has no solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865921/m22017-n3-has-no-solutions/1865946#1865946), but I had read the question wrong.  I pressed the Delete button but is there any way or need to wipe it off the books completely?

Comment: Not that I know of. I was somewhat self-conscious when I learned that 10k+ users could still see deleted answers. But, then I became 10k+ not long ago, and learned that ... well, most deleted answers aren't particularly interesting. I rarely pay any attention to them (if that's what you're worried about).

Comment: Ok.  I also see @quid's answer.  I do not like the idea that people can still see what I wanted to get rid of, hopefully admitting the mistake in the comment will soften the blow.

Comment: I get that. I'm just saying that, when I saw the deleted answers, they became much less exciting. There are deleted answers from the users with hundreds of thousands of reputation, and drifters who visit the site once to spam some other website (and everyone in between); it's mostly just noise, and everybody, at some point, posts something they'd like to unpost. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to do more than the regular delete that you did. In fact, there is even no effective way to do more by yourself. (I occasionally see users that edit their post into a blank post when deleting, but this is not good practice in my opinion. It does not really remove anything, as the revisions are preserved, while it creates a bump to the question,even when done after deletion.)

It is very rare that more is done to remove a post. If ever it should happen to you that you accidentally post something that you really *need* to get removed, say some sensitive data, flag the post for moderator attention and explain the problem. They can do something about it.

Comment: I will add reference to removal of posts containing sensitive data: [Can moderators / high-rep users delete revisions from the revision history?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57925/can-moderators-high-rep-users-delete-revisions-from-the-revision-history)

Comment: Well, you can always remove the content when it's within the first five minutes; but it is sometimes nicer to remove the content when the answer is long, as it saves a lot of scrolling for people who can access it.

Comment: @Asaf agreed, there may be some circumstances where it is reasonable. Though in the long answer case I'd prefer a stub was left to make clear the situation.